# How can we use Ternary Operator if no else statement is used?

Tags: java, conditional-operator

I have been currently wondering if we can ever use ternery operator in JAVA if only `if` statement is given, and no else part is to be executed. I worked a lot on it but couldn't find. Is it possible for us to use it this way?

Comment: would not be ternary.

Comment: It is _possible_ to use two `Runnable`s as the second and third operands of the ternary operator, then you can call `run` on it to run however many lines of code (including 0) you want in each branch. But should you? No.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following if statement having no else clause:

```
int x = 0;
if (something) {
    x = 5;
}
```

you have to give the variable a default value. Otherwise, it may not be initialized after the if statement, so you wouldn't be able to access it.

This can be written as a ternary conditional expression:

```
int x = something ? 5 : 0;
```

Of course, the original if statement can be re-written with else clause:

```
if (something) {
    x = 5;
} else {
    x = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical idiom for writing

```
if (condition) {
    x = newValue;
}
```

with a ternary operator is

```
x = condition ? newValue : x;
```

The idiom here is that when `condition` is `false`, the value of the ternary is the current value of `x`;  the entire statement then boils down to `x = x;`, which effectively does nothing.

You can decide for yourself which way is better...